# Can a quadratic polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x_{1},\dots,x_{d}]$ divide a linear one?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $2\leq d\ll p$ and $p$ is a prime. Consider the (nontrivial) polynomials $M(x_{1},\dots,x_{d})=x^{2}_{1}+\dots+x^{2}_{d}-c$ and $L(x_{1},\dots,x_{d})=a_{1}x_{1}+\dots+a_{d}x_{d}+a_{0}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x_{1},\dots,x_{d}]$. Is it possible that $M\vert L$, in the sense that $M(x)=0\Rightarrow L(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{F}_{p}^{d}$?

Remark 1: The answer to this question is false when $d=1$, since $(1+x^{2})(x-x^{3}+x^{5})=2x \mod \mathbb{F}_{7}$. In fact, by direct computation one can show that $(x^{2}-c)f(x)=1$ for some $f$ if and only if $c\neq 0$ and $x^{2}=c \mod p$ has a solution.

Remark 2: I have an analytic approach to this question. Let $A$ be the set of $x\in\mathbb{F}_{p}^{d}$ such that $M(x)=0$. Consider the exponential sum
$$\frac{1}{\vert A\vert}\sum_{x\in A}e^{\frac{2\pi i L(x)}{p}},$$
where $L(x)$ is viewed as the embedding of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ to $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. One can compute that this sum is $O(p^{-\frac{d-2}{2}})$ when $L$ is nontrivial (for example, see Lemma 3.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703504v2). This shows that the answer to the question is negative for $d\geq 3$ (and $d\ll p$). However, since this is an algebraic geometry question (I am not an expert in this field), is there a more direct way to answer this question?

Comment: No. The value $M(x)$ does not change if we change the signs of coordinates, but for $L$ it usually does. It remains to find a root of $M$ for which fixed $x_i$ is non-zero. That is possible if $p>3$: the sum of two non-zero squares may take arbitrary value.